# Не работает одна из функций связного списка

Tags: c++

Функция `add_after()` должна дополнять список после обнаружения в нем строки `a_word[]` строкой `a_word_after[]`. Обе строки вводятся пользователем после заполнения списка.
Компилятор указывает на отмеченную строку и пишет:

> error: incompatible types in assignment of 'char*' to 'char [80]'

Я так понимаю, невозможно присвоить указатель на символ к массиву символов? Но разве одномерный массив - это не указатель на нулевой элемент этого массива? Объясните, пожалуйста, как это исправить?

```
#include <iostream>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

struct node
{
    char word[80];
    node* ptrToNextNode;
};

void fillList(node *&list);
void prntList(node *list);
void makeList(node *&list);
void add_after(node *list,char a_word[],char a_word_after[]);

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    node* list;
    char a_word[80],a_word_after[80];
    fillList(list);
    prntList(list);
    cout<<"Input a_word: ";
    cin>>a_word;
    cout<<"Input a_word_after: ";
    cin>>a_word_after;
    add_after(list,a_word,a_word_after);
    prntList(list);
    return 0;
}
void fillList(node*& list)
{
    makeList(list);
    cout<<"Input word end press 'Enter'(input '.' for exit): ";
    cin>>list->word;
    if(!strcmp(".",list->word))
    {
        delete list;
        list=NULL;
    }
    node *current, *last;
    current=list;
    while(current!=NULL)
    {
        last=new node;
        cout<<"Input word end press 'Enter'(input '.' for exit): ";
        cin>>last->word;
        if(!strcmp(".",last->word))
        {
            delete last;
            last=NULL;
        }
        current->ptrToNextNode=last;
        current=last;
    }
}
void makeList(node *&list)
{
    list=new node;
    if(list==NULL)
    {
        cout<<"Not enough memory! Terminate program...";
        exit(1);
    }
    cout<<"List ready\n";
}
void prntList(node *list)
{
    if(list==NULL)
    {
        cout<<"This list is empty\n";
    }
    else
    {
        while(list!=NULL)
        {
            cout<<list->word<<endl;
            list=list->ptrToNextNode;
        }
        cout<<"//////////End of list//////////";
    }
}
void add_after(node *list,char a_word[],char a_word_after[])
{
    if(list==NULL)
    {
        cout<<"This list is empty";
    }
    else
    {
        while(list!=NULL)
        {
            if(!strcmp(list->word,a_word))
            {
                node* filling_pointer;
                makeList(filling_pointer);
                filling_pointer->word=a_word_after; //<---------------Ошибка в этой строке
                filling_pointer->ptrToNextNode=list->ptrToNextNode;
                list->ptrToNextNode=filling_pointer;
            }
            list=list->ptrToNextNode;
        }
        cout<<"//////////Pasting over//////////";
    }
}
```

Comment: Чтобы отформатировать код мне пришлось вбивать перед каждой новой строкой по 4 пробела. Только так можно отформатировать код?

Comment: @hal9000, Чтобы отформатировать код, выделите его мышью и нажмите на кнопку 101010 редактора.

Comment: выделите его мышью и нажмите на кнопку 101010 редактора.
Эта святая фраза должна быть написана в справке рядышком. Спасибо вам!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Дело в том, что имя массива, "созданного" (декларируемого) в функции это "фиктивный" (м.б. правильнее сказать *виртуальный*) указатель. Он фиктивен в том смысле, что изменить его значение нельзя (на самом деле постояная память для него не выделена, компилятор строит обращения к элементам массива, отталкиваясь от некой "базы" (обычно это один из регистров CPU)). Язык устроен так, что вы можете обращаться к **элементам** массива, используя синтаксис доступа по указателю.

Если массив передается как параметр функции, то существует **реальная** ячейка памяти (обычно  в стеке) в которой содержится адрес первого элемента массива. Аналогично для динамических массивов, которые Вы выделяете явно (например вызывая malloc()). В этом случае адрес начала массива Вы запоминаете в переменной типа указатель.

Небольшая иллюстрация:

```
  int a[4], *b;

  a[0] = 1;
  *(a+3) = 4;
  b = a+2;
  *b = 3;
  b[-1] = 2;
  printf ("%d %d %d %d\n",a[0],a[1],a[2],a[3]);
```

Напечатает: 1 2 3 4

Comment: Спасибо вам.

Answer (score 2):

Проблема в том что у тебя node::word уже указывает на массив char.
Тебе нужно не присваивать указатели, а копировать из одного массива в другой, например так: `strcpy(filling_pointer->word, a_word_after)`

Либо диамически перевыделять память для всех строк.

Comment: Проблема в том что у тебя node::word уже указывает на массив char.
Получается, что node::word это нечто вроде константного(неизменного) указателя?

Comment: потому что в функции main() - оба они также уже указывают на массив char[80] (т.е. надо использовать копирование из одного массива в другой), а в функцию копируются указатели на эти массивы (в данном случае char[] эквивалентно char*). Указатели уже можно переназначать, вызывать a_word=a_word_after, но результат никуда за пределы функции не уйдет и физически строки останутся неизменными

Comment: Спасибо вам.